# Loadingspinner while Images is loading from URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-flatlist

In my React Native applikation I render a `<FlatList>` with Images. I pass the direct imageurl as source into the `<Image>` Component.

```
<FlatList 
           data={this.state.images}
           keyExtractor={item => item.imageToken}
           renderItem={({ item }) => (                         
                    <Image key={item.imageToken} style={{ marginRight: 2, marginTop: 2, width: '50%', opacity: 1 }} source={{ uri: item.imageUrl }} alt="Alternate Text" size="xl" />    )}    />
```

This means that the images are loaded in a different order because they are also different sizes. I would like to show a placeholder during loading.

The `listAll()` function resets `isLoading` to **false** before all images are displayed. Is there a 'trigger' when an image is fully visible in the view? I can't just build a single state for each image - I guess.

There will be many hundreds of pictures!

I think it's important to know that I extract the url from the google firestore images and store they as an array in state beforehand. See function `getDownloadURL`

### Fullcode

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import { Image, FlatList, Center, Box } from "native-base"
import EventGalleryHeader from '../components/EventGalleryHeader.js'
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL, list, listAll } from "firebase/storage"
import { LongPressGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

export default class EventScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.storage = getStorage()
        this.pathToImages = '/eventimages/'
        this.eventImageSource = this.props.route.params.eventData.key
        this.imagesRef = this.pathToImages + this.eventImageSource
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            images: [],
            event: {
                adress: this.props.route.params.eventData.adress,
                hosts: this.props.route.params.eventData.hosts,
                description: this.props.route.params.eventData.description,
                eventtitle: this.props.route.params.eventData.eventtitle,
                invitecode: this.props.route.params.eventData.invitecode,
                key: this.props.route.params.eventData.key,
                timestamp: this.props.route.params.eventData.timestamp,
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getEventImageData()
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
    }

    getEventImageData() {
        const images = []
        const event = {
            adress: this.props.route.params.eventData.adress,
            description: this.props.route.params.eventData.description,
            eventtitle: this.props.route.params.eventData.eventtitle,
            key: this.props.route.params.eventData.key,
            timestamp: this.props.route.params.eventData.timestamp,
        }

        listAll(ref(this.storage, this.imagesRef))
            .then((res) => {
                res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {   
                    getDownloadURL(itemRef)
                        .then((url) => {

                            const indexOfToken = url.indexOf("&token=")
                            const token = url.slice(indexOfToken + 7)
                            images.push({
                                "imageUrl": url,
                                "imageToken": token
                            });
                            this.setState({
                                images,
                                event,
                                isLoading: false,
                            });
                            // console.log(this.state.images)
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            switch (error.code) {
                                case 'storage/object-not-found':
                                    break;
                                case 'storage/unauthorized':
                                    break;
                                case 'storage/canceled':
                                    break;
                                case 'storage/unknown':
                                    break;
                            }
                        });
                });

            }).catch((error) => {
            });
    }

    onLongPress = (event) => {
        if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
            alert("I've been pressed for 800 milliseconds");
        }
    };

    render() {

        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (<Center style={styles.container} _dark={{ bg: "blueGray.900" }} _light={{ bg: "blueGray.50" }}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#22d3ee" />
            </Center>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} >
                    <FlatList _dark={{ bg: "blueGray.900" }} _light={{ bg: "blueGray.50" }}
                        style={styles.list}
                        numColumns={2}
                        ListHeaderComponent={<EventGalleryHeader data={this.state.event} />}
                        data={this.state.images}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.imageToken}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => (
                            <LongPressGestureHandler
                                onHandlerStateChange={this.onLongPress}
                                minDurationMs={800}
                            >
                                <Image key={item.imageToken} style={{ marginRight: 2, marginTop: 2, width: '50%', opacity: 1 }} source={{ uri: item.imageUrl }} alt="Alternate Text" size="xl" />
                            </LongPressGestureHandler>
                        )}
                    />
                </SafeAreaView>
            );
        }
    };

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    image: {
        maxHeight: 450,
        width: '100%',
        height: 200,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    list: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    gallery: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'row',

    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And again it shows how important it is to read the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/image/) properly beforehand and to look there first if you have any questions.

You can achieve the behavior I mentioned above with the following parameters.

**loadingIndicatorSource** [link](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/image/#loadingindicatorsource)

Similarly to `source`, this property represents the resource used to render the loading indicator for the image, displayed until image is ready to be displayed, typically after when it got downloaded from network.

**onLoad** [link](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/image/#onload)

Invoked when load completes successfully.

**onLoadEnd** [link](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/image/#onloadend)

Invoked when load either succeeds or fails.

**onLoadStart** [link](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/image/#onloadstart)

Invoked on load start.

**Example:** `onLoadStart={() => this.setState({loading: true})}`